# (HTML/NextJS) Input Color Does Not Change When Declared Default Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

My color input appears not working/changing when declared default value (#ffffff)

[image]

But if I don't declare it, it works normally.

[image]

**Keep in mind that I am on a NextJS framework.**

```html
<input
    type='color'
    className={styles['change-bg']} /* Some css */
    value="#ffffff" /* the default value */
/>
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is too short, I mean the question topic is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `value` attribute use `defaultValue`, this will solve your problem.

**The following blog is from react and refer to this link for the reason:**
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values